# Single word which means 'suffix' or 'prefix'

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I would like to get a single word which means *suffix* or *prefix*.
I am creating a database table, which has columns - 'suffix' and 'prefix.'
I would like to name the table in such a way that on seeing the table name one should understand that the table has a collection of suffixes and/or prefixes.

Comment: *Affix* is the word you're looking for.

Comment: affixes it is. Thanks for the help. Would you like to add it as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [**Affix**](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=affix)

an additional element placed at the beginning or end of a root, stem, or word, or in the body of a word, to modify its meaning.

Comment: `Affix` is not entirely accurate as it includes infixes; [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adfix) suggests "adfix" but I guess it's a less common term (as I'd never heard it before)

Comment: *Affix* is no more than *Ad* + *figere* so even *adfix* would be understandable. :)

Comment: @blgt : the word indeed exists; thank you for the additional information. The Wiktionary page on *affix* classifies *adfix* as a hyponym of affix. ( http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/affix)

Answer (score 4):

If you expressly exclude **infixes**, such that the set contains only **prefixes** and **suffixes**, then the group would be *adfix,* a subset of *affix.*

> **[adfix](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adfix)** (*plural* adfixes)
>   A type of *affix*, which is attached to the **outside** of a stem (an existing word), to form a new word. The adfix category branches into *prefixes* (ones which appear before the stem) and *suffixes* (ones which appear after the stem). [emphasis added]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This word is new to me. I am choosing `affix` due to the popularity of the word. I think the word `adfix` is unknown to masses.

Comment: @Rohith Understandable. Even *infix* is less widely known.

Answer (score 3):

*[Affix](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/affix#Noun)* is appropriate.  Per wiktionary, it means:

> (linguistics) A bound morpheme added to a word’s stem; formerly applied only to suffixes (also called postfixes), the term as now used comprises prefixes, suffixes, infixes, circumfixes, and suprafixes.

Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix),

> An affix is a morpheme that is attached to a word stem to form a new word. Affixes may be derivational, like English *-ness* and *pre-*, or inflectional, like English plural *-s* and past tense *-ed*. They are bound morphemes by definition; prefixes and suffixes may be separable affixes. Affixation is, thus, the linguistic process speakers use to form different words by adding morphemes (affixes) at the beginning (prefixation), the middle (infixation) or the end (suffixation) of words.