# Why does the word ‘suffix’ have a double ‘ff’ while ‘prefix’ has a single ‘f’?

Tags: etymology, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, latin

While writing the word ‘*suffix*’, I stopped to do a spellcheck as a result of the ‘*ff*’. I did not do so with the word ‘*prefix*’ as I was comfortable with the ‘*pre*’ and ‘*fix*’. I looked up ‘ff’ vs. ‘f’ and found the Floss rule (also [FSZL](https://www.fisher-hill.com/the-fszl-rule/)), a spelling rule where the letters f, s, z, and l are doubled after a short vowel sound.

Then it became double the letter after a short vowel and don’t double if there is a consonant after the sound ([spellzone.com](https://www.spellzone.com/unit-02/page5.cfm)).

I did not feel that my question was answered.

The etymologies are as follows:

> **Prefix:** mid 16th century (as a verb): from Old French
> *prefixer*, from Latin *praefixus* ‘fixed in front’, from the verb
> *praefigere*, from *prae* ‘before’ + *figere* ‘to fix’. The noun is from
> modern Latin *praefixum*, neuter (used as a noun) of *praefixus*, and
> dates from the mid 17th century.
>
> **Suffix:** late 18th century (as a noun): from modern Latin *suffixum*,
> neuter past participle (used as a noun) of Latin *suffigere*, from *sub-*
> ‘subordinately’ + *figere* ‘fasten’.
>
> (Google)

Wouldn’t it make sense as ‘*preffix*’ and ‘*suffix*’, or ‘*prefix*’ and ‘*sufix*’?

Some tentatively related discussions are here: ["Postfix" or "suffix"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81263/postfix-or-suffix) and [Single word which means 'suffix' or 'prefix'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187788/single-word-which-means-suffix-or-prefix).

Comment: Your research shows double-f already in Latin *suffixum* and single-f in Latin *praefixus*.  So the question of single or double f is not one for English to answer.

Comment: Last time I entered a long lettered source, it didnt go well! Ah it's under google as: Definitions from Oxford languages. I'm trying to learn how to copy links correctly. Thanks @Cascabel

Comment: No problem, Huggy. I remember what it was like--twice!

Comment: OK @GEdgar. Thanks. Is this a latin question, i.e. pre and post, front and back? I didn't want to,further get into Suffix and postfix, but simply the rules for the ll vs single l

Comment: Suffering succotash!

Comment: Sylvester?? Am I wrong?

Comment: Just a guess: 'Suffix' has *ff* because consonants often get doubled after short vowels ('suffix' has a short vowel before the 'ff'). 'Prefix' has a single *f* because the vowel before the 'f' is long. Also see other words in which the consonant gets doubled after a short vowel: bitter, better, hotter, sitter etc. (Take it with a huge pinch of salt.)

Comment: Looking at it strictly from an English pronunciation standpoint, "sufix" would have a long "u" sound (*soofix*); conversely, "preffix" would have a short "e" sound, as in "preference", which of course, brings up another question entirely.

Comment: Thanks all. But parallelogram? So easy to get lost in translation. I had no problem spelling that one - but from memory.

Comment: Moreover, the 'b' of *sub-* [assimilated](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/553135/365490) to an 'f' in anticipation of the following 'f' in Latin. The root of *pre-* didn't have a terminal consonant, so no assimilation took place.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul. That sounds good. I'm currently looking at 'prepends', a word I've never encountered

Comment: @Huggy: Where did you see 'prepend'? (I'm sure I've used it somewhere...)

Comment: @Decapitated Soul. I was reveiewing another stack exchange question earlier. I'm sure it was related to Suffix/Postfix. The entry asked of someone roughly 'I'm sure at you level you should have come across prepend before...' Just some homework. As now I'm on to terminal consonants!

Comment: "Prepend" is an invention of Indian English.  But has begun to be used by computer programmers in other places.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> These words are 'borrowed' from Latin, which routinely performed [*elision*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision) and [*assimilation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(linguistics)) on prefixes with a final consonant when the consonant was sufficiently similar to the initial consonant of the root to which it was attached. The resulting word was spelled with a doubling of the remaining consonant.
>
> > pre- + fix- ... no final consonant, so *prefix*
> > sub- + fix- ... so *suffix*
> > ad- + fix- ...  *affix*
> >
> > in- + toler- ... {n} and {t} are very high contrast, so *intolerant*
> > in- + med- ... *immediate*
> > in- + lum- ... *illuminate*
>
> The same pattern is followed with modern coinages using Latin prefixes and roots.

([From English Language and Learners SE by StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10774/prefix-and-suffix-issue))

Comment: Note that it's *prae* in Latin.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways you can explain it are from the word's etymology, and from the word's pronunciation in English. Etymology is the historical reason. The English pronunciation is not the original cause of the spelling, but if you remember the pronunciation, it might help you to remember the spelling.

#### Etymological explanation

The etymological reason is that, as mentioned in the comments, the Latin source of *suffix* (the verb *suffigere*) has double *ff*, but the Latin source of *prefix* (the verb *praefigere*) has single *f*.

The Latin verb *suffigere* was formed with the prefix *sub-,* which in its basic form ends in the consonant *b.* However, Latin has rules that cause consonants at the ends of certain prefixes to merge with the following consonant to form a double consonant in some circumstances. In the case of *sub-,* the *b* is turned into *f* before a base starting in the consonant *f* (this is called “assimilation”), creating a double *ff*.

The Latin verb *praefigere* was formed with the prefix *prae-,* which does not end in a consonant, so there was no doubling in Latin.

#### An alternative explanation from English pronunciation

In English, a vowel before a double consonant tends to be pronounced “short”. You can see that *suffix* is pronounced with a “short u” sound in the first syllable, which is consistent with the spelling with double *ff* (although it does not require it: there are prefixed words such as *suburb* where the *u* is pronounced short despite not being followed by a double consonant).

In contrast, *prefix* is pronounced with a “long e” sound in the first syllable. It would be fairly irregular if a word with this pronunciation were spelled with double *ff* after the *e*.

Comment: are you saying the pronounciation of the geminate was not affecting the affix, in latin? That is unlikely because i would imply spelling prounciations, that is but unlikely in general.

Comment: @vectory: I'm saying the spelling of the word is (mostly) not based on the *English* pronunciation. It is based on the Latin pronunciation